# Can not change camera in mobile Chrome or Safari during WebRTC call

Tags: android, webrtc

I use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` to retrieve list of all video devices (`element.kind === 'videoinput'`) and then call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` call to rotate video devices (using deviceId as constraint). Everything works fine on Windows Chrome / Firefox, but on android phone (tried Samsung, Asus, Huawei with Android 8/9) this call fails for **back camera** with NotReadableError / Could not start video source (for Chrome) or AbortError / Starting video failed (for Firefox).
Strangely same code works ok in iOS / Safari.
Also this only happens when WebRTC call is present in browser. If there is no call I can select any video device.
Also if I select back camera first and try to establish the call, it does not work, I get similar error.
I know it's far-fetched but maybe someone had same/similar issue?
All browser versions are up-to-date.

[UPDATE - code snippet and log]

```
switchCamera() {
try {
  if (this.localStream) {
    const tracks = this.localStream.getTracks();
    console.log('switchCamera stopping this.localStream tracks', tracks);
    tracks.forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
      console.log('switchCamera stopping track', track);
      track.stop();
    });
    console.log('switchCamera stop stream');
  }

  const constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: { facingMode: this.faceCamera ? 'environment' : 'face' }
  };
  this.faceCamera = !this.faceCamera;
  console.log('switchCamera constraints: ', constraints);
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
      console.log('getUserMedia:', stream);
      this.logText('got stream');

      this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;

      const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
      const audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
      console.log('videoTracks', videoTracks);
      if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Using video device: ${videoTracks[0].label}`);
      }

      const videoTrack = videoTracks[0];
      const audioTrack = audioTracks[0];

      console.log('Replacing track for pc', videoTrack, audioTrack);

      const pc = this.session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;

      const videoSender = pc.getSenders().find(s => {
        return s.track && s.track.kind === videoTrack.kind;
      });
      const audioSender = pc.getSenders().find(s => {
        return s.track && s.track.kind === audioTrack.kind;
      });

      if (videoSender) {
        console.log('videoSender.replaceTrack', videoTrack);
        videoSender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
      }
      if (audioSender) {
        console.log('audioSender.replaceTrack', audioTrack);
        audioSender.replaceTrack(audioTrack);
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('getUserMedia error:', e.name, e.code, e.message);
    });
} catch (e) {
  window.alert(e);
}
}
```

this is the log from chrome remote device debug:

[image]

The error is "NotReadableError", "Could not start video source" which means that the underlying device handle could not be obtained by chrome.
Again, safari/ios works ok.

Answer (score 1):

To switch between front and back cameras on mobile, you need to stop the previous stream before opening a new stream.

```
if (videoIn.srcObject) {
  videoIn.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
  track.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices, there is a dedicated way of how to select between front & back camera.

`VideoFacingMode` - https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#dom-videofacingmodeenum

TL;DR

```
window.navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
    if (devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput').length > 1) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {facingMode: 'user' /*'environment'*/}}).then(console.log.bind(this))
    }   
})
```

It works for mobile Safari, Chrome and FF.

> NOTE
>
> Remember, to stop the previous video track before calling the
>   `getUserMedia` with `video` again, otherwise, you will get an
>   exception.

Comment: Mariusz, thanks for answer, but have you *actually* tried it *during WebRTC call*? I did try with 'facingMode', but in my case it doesn't matter how I specify rear camera constraints (with deviceId or facingMode) I still get the same error. Yes, I do stop tracks.
Again, all is ok when there is no WebRTC call.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Could you please paste your code snippet to reproduce the issue? What's the error description? Which method throws the exception?

Comment: Mariusz, I've added code and log from chrome remote debug. The error is thrown at "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)" line and handled in promise "catch(e => ...") clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I narrowed it down to calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` in `ngInit()` (this is Angular app).
Even if I remove all code in `.then()` handler function, the effect is the same.
Only removing this call solves the issue.
Not sure at this time why such behavior, will investigate it more thoroughly and update.

Comment: did you find anything more on this? I am also facing the same issue